# TFS2010:Branching from one team project to another

Tags: branching-and-merging

I am using TFS 2010.I have two team project--$project1  and $Project2
They look like-
   $project1
       dev
       rel
   $project2
       main

Now I want to branch from $project1->dev  to $project2, but I am getting error as "TF10169:Unsupported pending change attempted..."

Can anyone let me know is it possible to branch from one team project to another?

Answer (score 4):

Branching from one Team Project to another is fully supported.

If you have a copy of Project1 mapped to your local workspace try doing a Get Latest.  For completeness do a Get Specific Version and then select Latest Version to overwrite all locals rather than just Get Latest.

I've seen this error before albeit unrelated to a branch, when deletes have been pending.

Comment: You're very welcome.  Please consider marking answers as accepted if they helped you solve your problem.